# Codeigniter | .htaccess makes 403

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm new to Codeigniter, and unfortunately i'm new in .htaccess. I have a sample CI script that i want to learn.
Everytime i open this CI script always get 403 forbidden, buat when i delete the .htaccess it loads normally.
I'm sure there must be a problem with .htaccess.

I install this script in an addon domain that point to folder /public_html/newdomain.com
Yes, i installed it in subfolder, not in the main folder.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F62ZZ.png)

and here is my .htaccess

```
# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
# change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
# RewriteBase /

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isnt true it sends the
    # request to the front controller, index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

# Ensure Authorization header is passed along
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we dont have mod_rewrite installed, all 404
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

# Disable server signature start
ServerSignature Off
# Disable server signature end
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(css|flv|gif|htm|html|ico|jpe|jpeg|jpg|js|mp3|mp4|png|pdf|swf|txt)$">
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive Off
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        FileETag None
        Header unset ETag
        Header unset Pragma
        Header unset Cache-Control
        Header unset Last-Modified
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Expires "jue, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74___lsphp .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

I'm sure the error is in this .htaccess, unfortunately i'm begiiner in apache directives. Hopefully somebody help me. Thanks.
This scripts works perfect if i install it in main public_html. But i get 403 when i installed it in subfolder above.
Thanks.
I have wrote this quenstion in Codeigniter Official Forum, but after more than 24 hours no publish from moderator so i go to stackoverflow. Thanks.

Whenever i try to load my codeigniter, i always get 403. When i delete the .htaccess , it works perfecly.

Comment: What URL(s) are you requesting?

Comment: i don't request any url. i just open my addon domain www.myaddondomain.com , then 403. But when i delete this .htaccess, everithing works fine. I don't want to delete .htacess, i just want to fix my .htaccess.

Comment: So actually you request the url `https://www.myaddondomain.com/`, right?

Comment: Http status 403 means "forbidden". That points towards either a permission issue on file system level or within the apache configuration of that virtual host ("addon domain"). Or an issue within that script itself, if it performs some sort of authorization. We cannot say. But this does not exactly point towards an issue _within_ that distributed configuration file you posted (".htaccess"). So _why_ are you "sure" that is is cause of the issue?

Comment: Thanks @arkascha, yes, this is just a codeigniter script. if i put this script to myaddondomain.com that point to /public_html/myaddondomain.com/ folder then it always display 403, but if i delete .htaccess it works fine. If i put it in my premiere domain wwww.mypremieredomain.com that  point to /public_html/ , it displays normal. i'm learning it now,,,

Comment: That is what you already wrote before. But it does not in any form address what I pointed out in my comment.

Comment: commenting AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74___lsphp .php .php7 .phtml solve the problem.